# Reading from child pipe after fork gets stuck in the read loop in an unknown location

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I am writing a program where I have forked twice to create 2 child processes which send information to the parent via their stdouts. The children start the program making it recursive. What happens is that the parent, while reading the child, gets stuck in the read loop, but it is not a forever loop (there is finite and expected output); it just doesn't move past it.

```
        char response1[256];
        double complex r1[sizeof(workable)/sizeof(float)];
        char* thing = NULL;
        int countC1 = 1;
        int bytesread;
        char* response1Whole = NULL;

        while((bytesread = read(pipefdc1b[0],response1, 256)) > 0){
          fprintf(stderr,"PID:%d -> Reading Bytes from Child 1 Bytes read: %d\n\n", getpid(), bytesread);
          if(bytesread == 256){
            response1Whole = (char*) realloc(response1Whole, countC1*256 );
          }else{
            response1Whole = (char*) realloc(response1Whole, (countC1-1)*256+bytesread);
          }
          strcat(response1Whole, response1);

          countC1++;
          fprintf(stderr,"PID:%d -> Current Builts Input %s\n\n", getpid(), response1Whole);
        }

        fprintf(stderr,"PID:%d -> Child 1 Read\n\n", getpid());
```

This is the code snippet I believe is getting stuck. It prints out all of the "Current built input" and "Reading Bytes from Child 1" parts but never reaches the "Child 1 Read" Part. Notable there is a finite and deterministic output, and the things it does read are what is expected, the program just stops.

```
if(count == 1){
    fprintf(stdout,"%s", st);
    fflush(stdout);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

This is the Block of code that determines the output. I feel like there might be some issue here where it doesn't terminate it's output stream properly, but then again it does exit.

Here is the code from creating pipes to the "problem" area:

```
int pipefdc1a[2];  //p->c1
int pipefdc1b[2];  //c1->p||

int pipefdc2a[2];  //p->c1
int pipefdc2b[2];  //c2->p

if(pipe(pipefdc1a) == -1){
  fprintf(stderr, "Pipe Creation Failed\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if(pipe(pipefdc1b) == -1){
  fprintf(stderr, "Pipe Creation Failed\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if(pipe(pipefdc2a) == -1){
  fprintf(stderr, "Pipe Creation Failed\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if(pipe(pipefdc2b) == -1){
  fprintf(stderr, "Pipe Creation Failed\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
//fprintf(stderr,"PID:%d -> Pipes Created\n\n", getpid());
fflush(stdout);
pid_t pid = fork();
pid_t pid2;

switch (pid) {
  case -1:

    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot fork!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  case 0:
    //child 1
    close(pipefdc1a[1]);
    close(pipefdc1b[0]);
    close(pipefdc2a[0]);
    close(pipefdc2a[1]);
    close(pipefdc2b[0]);
    close(pipefdc2b[1]);

    dup2(pipefdc1a[0],STDIN_FILENO);
    close(pipefdc1a[0]);

    dup2(pipefdc1b[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(pipefdc1b[1]);

    execlp("./forkFFT","forkFFT", NULL);

    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  default:
    //parent
    fflush(stdout);
    pid2 = fork();
    switch(pid2){
      case -1:
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot fork!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      case 0:
        //child 2
        //fprintf(stderr,"PID:%d -> New Child 2 Created\n\n", getpid());
        close(pipefdc1a[1]);
        close(pipefdc1a[0]);
        close(pipefdc1b[0]);
        close(pipefdc1b[1]);
        close(pipefdc2a[1]);
        close(pipefdc2b[0]);

        dup2(pipefdc2a[0],STDIN_FILENO);
        close(pipefdc2a[0]);

        dup2(pipefdc2b[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(pipefdc2b[1]);

        execlp("./forkFFT","forkFFT", NULL);

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      default:
        //parent


        fprintf(stderr, "entered parent switch. PID1: %d, PID2: %d\n\n", pid, pid2);

        write(pipefdc1a[1], stp1, evensize);
        write(pipefdc2a[1], stp2, oddsize);
        close(pipefdc1a[1]);
        close(pipefdc2a[1]);

        char response1[256];
        char response2[256];
        double complex r1[sizeof(workable)/sizeof(float)];
        double complex r2[sizeof(workable)/sizeof(float)];
        char* thing = NULL;
        int countC1 = 1;
        int bytesread;
        char* response1Whole = NULL;



        while((bytesread = read(pipefdc1b[0],response1, 256)) > 0){
          fprintf(stderr,"PID:%d -> Reading Bytes from Child 1 Bytes read: %d\n\n", getpid(), bytesread);
          if(bytesread == 256){
            response1Whole = (char*) realloc(response1Whole, countC1*256 );
          }else{
            response1Whole = (char*) realloc(response1Whole, (countC1-1)*256+bytesread);
          }
          strcat(response1Whole, response1);

          countC1++;
          fprintf(stderr,"PID:%d -> Current Builts Input %s\n\n", getpid(), response1Whole);
        }

        fprintf(stderr,"PID:%d -> Child 1 Read\n\n", getpid());
        char* token = strtok(response1Whole, "\n");
        while(token != NULL){
          double real = (double)strtof(token, &thing);
          if(token == thing){
            fprintf(stderr, "Real Part is NAN\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
          }
          fprintf(stderr, "Real Number Read from child 1: %lf. PID1: %d, PID2: %d\n\n", real, pid, pid2);
          double imaginary = 0.0;
          if(thing != NULL){
            fprintf(stderr,"Thing String: %s\n", thing);
            char* check = NULL;
            imaginary = (double)strtof(thing, &check);
            if(check == thing){
              fprintf(stderr, "Imaginary Part is NAN\n");
              exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
          }
          fprintf(stderr, "Imaginary part of number 1: %lf. PID1: %d, PID2: %d\n\n",imaginary, pid, pid2);
          r1[countC1] = real + imaginary*I;
          token = strtok(NULL,"\n");
        }

        fprintf(stderr, "made it 1!\n\n");

        char* thing2 = NULL;
        int countC2 = 0;
        FILE* pipe2File = fdopen(pipefdc2b[0], "r");
        while(fgets(response2, 256, pipe2File) != NULL){
          fprintf(stderr, "Reading from child 2. PID1: %d, PID2: %d\n\n", pid, pid2);

          double real = (double)strtof(response2, &thing2);
          if(response1 == thing2){
            fprintf(stderr, "Real Part is NAN\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
          }
          fprintf(stderr, "Real Number Read from child 2: %lf. PID1: %d, PID2: %d\n\n", real, pid, pid2);
          double imaginary = 0.0;
          if(thing2 != NULL && thing2[0] != '\n'){
            fprintf(stderr,"Thing2 String: %s\n", thing2);
            char* check2 = NULL;
            imaginary = (double)strtof(thing2, &check2);
            if(check2 == thing2){
              fprintf(stderr, "Imaginary Part is NAN\n");
              exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
          }
          fprintf(stderr, "Imaginary part of number 2: %lf. PID1: %d, PID2: %d\n\n",imaginary, pid, pid2);
          r2[countC2] = real + imaginary*I;
          countC2++;
        }

        fclose(pipe2File);
        fprintf(stderr, "made it 2!\n\n");

        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        if(status == 1){
          fprintf(stderr, "Child did not terminate normally!\n");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        waitpid(pid2, &status, 0);
        if(status == 1){
          fprintf(stderr, "Child did not terminate normally!\n");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
```

I tried 2 different loops for child 1 and 2 because I at some point figured that was the problem but it wasn't.

I am somewhat at the limit of my understanding of C; if you could answer and explain that would be great.

I'm trying to abide by the 'Minimal required code' rule, but if you feel like other things are required please ask and I will add them.

Comment: The code where you create the pipe(s) and close the unused file descriptors is most important.  Note of that is shown. It’s an odds-on get that you aren’t closing enough file descriptors.

Comment: I added the chunk

Comment: The children correctly close the pipe descriptors. But the parent doesn’t close any, so it’ll never get EOF because it has the write end of the pipes it reads from still open.

Answer (score 0):

As I guessed in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53764592/reading-from-child-pipe-after-fork-gets-stuck-in-the-read-loop-in-an-unknown-loc#comment94381226_53764592), you aren't closing enough file descriptors — this time, the problem is in the parent, though it is often the child processes that don't do enough closing.

---

**Rule of thumb**: If you
[`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)
one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the
original file descriptors returned by
[`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html)
as soon as possible.
In particular, you should close them before using any of the
[`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html)
family of functions.

The rule also applies if you duplicate the descriptors with either
[`dup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html)
or
[`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html)
with `F_DUPFD`

---

You create 8 file descriptors via the 4 `pipe()` calls.  In the children, you close them according to the rule of thumb.

However, your parent only closes 2 file descriptors before trying to read from the children to EOF.  And, since it still has the write end of the pipes that it is reading from open, it will never get an EOF indication because it could, in theory, write to the pipe.

So, your parent code that looks like this:

```
    write(pipefdc1a[1], stp1, evensize);
    write(pipefdc2a[1], stp2, oddsize);
    close(pipefdc1a[1]);
    close(pipefdc2a[1]);
```

should look more like:

```
    write(pipefdc1a[1], stp1, evensize);
    write(pipefdc2a[1], stp2, oddsize);
    close(pipefdc1a[1]);
    close(pipefdc2a[1]);
    close(pipefdc1a[0]);  // Extra
    close(pipefdc2a[0]);  // Extra
    close(pipefdc1b[1]);  // Extra
    close(pipefdc2b[1]);  // Read all about it!
```

I think you need to look at writing functions to do the work rather than having all the code in the `main()` program, but you'd still have to deal with calling `close()` often enough.